# SameSite attribute in asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, security, firefox

I have developed a website using asp.net mvc and i've used some third party libraries.When i run in locally then it shows me following message in my Console.

> > A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://dtscdn.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

What is this ? Why this came ? any security issue ?

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is changing how cookies work.  You are using a strategy that will break in the future.  Latest version of ASP.NET allows you to set a SameSite=None attribute that would fix this.  See the Microsoft link below for the needed useragent and attribute settings.

References: https://auth0.com/blog/browser-behavior-changes-what-developers-need-to-know/
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/samesite/system-web-samesite